# vaapi permission issue in vaainfo

Tags: intel, drm

I'm running into some trouble to get my intel i965 driver working with vaapi support.

Currently the vaapi support is only working as root user. If I run vaainfo as non root user I get the following message:

```
[heiko@localhost ~]$ /bin/vainfo 
libva info: VA-API version 0.34.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 1
libva error: va_getDriverName() failed with operation failed,driver_name=i965
vaInitialize failed with error code 1 (operation failed),exit
```

with root permissions (everything looks fine vlc is working fine with vaapi):

```
[heiko@localhost ~]$ sudo vainfo 
libva info: VA-API version 0.34.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/dri/i965_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_0_34
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
vainfo: VA-API version: 0.34 (libva 1.2.1)
vainfo: Driver version: Intel i965 driver - 1.2.1.pre1
vainfo: Supported profile and entrypoints
  VAProfileMPEG2Simple            : VAEntrypointVLD
  VAProfileMPEG2Main              : VAEntrypointVLD
  VAProfileH264Baseline           : VAEntrypointVLD
  VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointVLD
  VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointVLD
```

whats wrong with my installation??

```
   [heiko@localhost ~]$ getfacl /dev/dri/card0 
    getfacl: Entferne führende '/' von absoluten Pfadnamen
    # file: dev/dri/card0
    # owner: root
    # group: video
    user::rw-
    user:heiko:rw-
    group::rw-
    mask::rw-
    other::rw-
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when using E18 as my desktop environment.
Using gnome-shell solved the issue with vainfo for me.
Another workaround that I found was to unset the variable $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR.

```
    unset XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
```

I have no idea why this helps, but it did make a difference for me.
I also found another possible workaround, but it did not work on my case:
https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/490090
Maybe it does work for you.

Comment: In my case, the issue was with vaapi and iHD. Unsetting XDG_RUNTIME_DIR along with setting LIBVA_DRIVER_NAME (vaapi specific) fixed the issue. In my previous OS install/build, I didn't have to do either for vainfo to work. BTW, this is in GNOME.

Answer (score 1):

Add yourself to the video group and log in again:

```
sudo usermod -a -G video $USER
```

Then retest.